# How to remove dots between numbers in column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can I remove these dots in between numbers?

```
df <- data.frame(c("0303.12.00" ,"0303.13.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.23.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.23.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.29.00", "0303.31.00"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by:

```
df <- c("0303.12.00" ,"0303.13.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.23.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.23.00" ,"0303.23.00", "0303.29.00", "0303.31.00")
gsub("\\.", "", df)
[1] "03031200" "03031300" "03032300" "03032300" "03032300" "03032300" "03032300" "03032900" "03033100"
```